# The amount of variables used in SEM models

Tags: r, categorical-data, maximum-likelihood, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I would like to use lavaan for SEM. I am have however struggling to get things running (I went through al the examples, but they always deal with these perfect datasets). The only thing that has worked is one regression with some (five) variables as I would put into any OLS.

When I use more variables, like 10 or 15, I get the message: `Warning message:
In lavaan::lavaan(model = ..., data = ..., model.type = "sem",  :
  lavaan WARNING: the optimizer warns that a solution has NOT been found!`

Now, I have three questions about this:

1. Does SEM indeed get into trouble when I use many variables?
2. Can I circumvent this by setting starting values (for example from OLS estimates)?
3. Is similarly to OLS, the outcome biased in a misspecified model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does SEM indeed get into trouble when I use many variables?

It doesn't 'get into trouble' but it can have more difficulty estimating the parameters, especially if the sample size is small.

2. Can I circumvent this by setting starting values (for example from OLS estimates)?

Almost certainly not. The program picks good starting values on its own, using better approaches.

3. Is similarly to OLS, the outcome biased in a misspecified model?

Yes.

P.S. I have edited your question, because none of this is specific to Lavaan.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! So if I understand you correctly, I could only look at OLS to make an educated guess on which variables to put in or not put in, and perhaps the functional form? Any other things I could do, to reduce the possibility of non-conversion?

Comment: This is a whole set of additional questions about the extent to which you can legitimately explore models without risking overfitting.  What's your sample size?

Comment: I can write a new question if that is preferable. I have maximum of about 100.000 observations, from 50.000 participants, so for SEM purposes; 50.000 I guess. The actual amount of the sample size is heavily dependent on the variables I select, but I generally make sure that sample sizes stay above 20.000.

Comment: I would put your whole model as a new question - it might be obvious what the problem is (or it might not ...)